# Разный контент на одной теме в мультисайтовости Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт, нужно разделить по городам ( будут разные товары, контент в хедере, контакты и тд). Сделал доп. сайт в системе мультисайт Wordpress. Выбрал ту же тему, и столкнулся с проблемой: в хедер и индекс затягивается вёрстка из основного сайта. Мне почти так и надо, только хочу сделать разный контент в хедере ( другие номера телефонов ), возможно на главной в вёрстке что-то поменять. Можно как-то разделить их?

Или придётся всё запихивать в один хедер и индекс, а потом с помощью проверок показывать разные блоки? Не хотелось бы так.

Спасибо

Comment: Добавляй виджеты в нужные шаблоны.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сети сайтов у каждого сайта создаются уникальные таблицы под каждый сайт

```
    #__commentmeta
    #__comments
    #__links
    #__options
    #__postmeta 
    #__posts
    #__termmeta
    #__terms
    #__term_relationships
    #__term_taxonomy
```

Если телефоны, контакты в верстке статично сделаны, то нужно вынести их в настройки темы и тогда под каждый сайт будут загружаться индивидуальные настройки.

Comment: Кхм, а это идея. Не подскажите, как это сделать? Был бы рад ссылочке на материал

Comment: @Ex1st если у Вас уже создана сеть сайтов, то стандартные функции будут возвращать разные результаты в зависимости от сайта. (get_option)